# Can $\operatorname{Tr} f(M)$ for matrices $M$ be upper bounded by $\sum_{i=1}^n f(M_{ii})$?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, trace

For a convex, analytic function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and a real-valued, symmetric matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ we have the bound

$$\operatorname{Tr} f(M) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n f (M_{ii}).$$

Here $f(M)$ denotes the matrix function of $f$ applied to $M$, not the element-wise application of $f$ to $M$.

Can the trace of $f(M)$ be similarly upper bounded by the trace of the element-wise application of $f$ to $M$? In particular I am interested in a bound for $f(x) = x^{-1}$ applied to positive-definite matrices.

Comment: $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, so as-written, the expression $f(M)$ is not defined for $M\not\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e., when it's any (non $1\times 1$) matrix.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry for the confusion, by $f(M)$ I mean matrix function of an analytic function $f$ applied to $M$ (e.g. the matrix functions $\exp(M)$ or $\sin(M)$).

Comment: Is the spectral radius of $M$ smaller than the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ about $0$? (I don't know if it's a necessary condition for $f(M)$, but it's a sufficient condition to rewrite the trace of $f(M)$ in a way that avoids knowing what $f(M)$ is)

Comment: If $M$ is indefinite, the answer is no. E.g. let $M$ be a nonzero symmetric matrix with a zero diagonal and $f(x)=x^2$. Then the value of any function of $f(m_{11}),\ldots,f(m_{nn})$ will be a constant. However, the trace of $f(M)=M^2$ is not bounded above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample for $f(x) = x^{-1}$, which is mentioned as of particual interest, but it does not fit to the assumptions on $f$ in the question.

Define for $\epsilon>0$
$$
A = \pmatrix{ 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 + \epsilon},
$$
which is positive definite.
Its inverse is
$$
A^{-1} = \epsilon^{-1}\pmatrix{ 1+ \epsilon &- 1 \\ -1 & 1 },
$$
with trace $tr(A^{-1}) = \frac{2+\epsilon}\epsilon$, which explodes for $\epsilon\searrow0$. However, the sum of the inverses of the diagonal elements of $A$ is $1 + \frac1{1+\epsilon}$, which is bounded.

---

Here is a counterexample for $f(x) = \exp(x)$. Define
$$
A = \pmatrix{ 2t & t \\ t & 2t},
$$
with $t>0$. It has eigenvalues $t$ and $3t$. Then $tr(f(A)) = \exp(t) + \exp(3t)$, while $\sum_i f(a_{ii}) = 2\exp(2t)$.
And
$$
\frac{ tr(f(A)) }{ \sum_i f(a_{ii}) } = \frac12 (\exp(-t) + \exp(+t))
$$
which is unbounded for $t\to +\infty$.